# PWA 2013 - “An item with the same key has already been added”

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, project-server

Suddenly my PWA 2013 started showing the error below (extracted from Event Viewer)

```
Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 11/25/2013 12:37:05 PM 
Event time (UTC): 11/25/2013 2:37:05 PM 
Event ID: 347fe626e1274a4a96fb2afc7e537b44  Event sequence: 194  Event
occurrence: 193  Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/3/ROOT/bea8a2b7b12941f1bc7b6a7ea02f25b6-1-130298629694620451

Trust level: Full 
Application Virtual Path: /bea8a2b7b12941f1bc7b6a7ea02f25b6 
Application Path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\15.0\WebServices\Shared\ProjectServer\ 
Machine name: XXXX

Process information: 
Process ID: 6040 
Process name: w3wp.exe 
Account name: XXXX\svc.sharepoint.app 

Exception information: 
Exception type: ArgumentException 
Exception message: An item with the same key has already been added.    at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult
result)    at
System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult
result)    at
System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.OnAsyncEventCompletion(IAsyncResult
ar)

Request information: 
Request URL: http://asdfg:32843/bea8a2b7b12941f1bc7b6a7ea02f25b6/PSI/psiserviceapp.svc

Request path: /bea8a2b7b12941f1bc7b6a7ea02f25b6/PSI/psiserviceapp.svc 
User host address: ::1 
User:  
Is authenticated: False 
Authentication Type:  
Thread account name: XXXX\svc.sharepoint.app 

Thread information: 
Thread ID: 16 
Thread account name: XXXX\svc.sharepoint.app 
Is impersonating: False 
Stack trace:    at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)   
at
System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult
result)    at
System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.OnAsyncEventCompletion(IAsyncResult
ar)
```

I've been searching for some clue about it but wasn't able to find anything really close to my problem. Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a fix for it.
It was a problem with the User Profile Service Application. I just managed to start it correctly and the problem is now gone.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question was posted a long time ago but I also had this problem and maybe my solution can help others.

I got this error when there is more than one event handler registered for the same event. For example if you have two event handlers on Proejct Created. While it may not be your case, it is still something worth checking.